# How to make order history to online shop in php?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**Problems**:

1) Just 3 `id_penjualan` rows were displayed in order history, it should be 4 `id_penjualan` rows.

2) `jumlah` and `total` have same value, it should be different for each other depending on sum of product quantity  of each transaction.

**Table** `tb_penjualan`:
[image: tb_penjualan]

**Table**: `tb_detail_penjualan`:
[image: tb_detail_penjualan]

**Output**:
[image: order history]

**Code**:

```
<?php
$id_pelanggan=$_SESSION['user_session'];
$query="SELECT  tb_penjualan.*, tb_pelanggan.nama_dpn, tb_pelanggan.nama_blk
    FROM tb_penjualan LEFT JOIN tb_pelanggan
    ON tb_penjualan.id_pelanggan=tb_pelanggan.id_pelanggan
    WHERE tb_penjualan.id_pelanggan=:id_pelanggan
    AND tb_penjualan.checkout='yes' ORDER BY id_penjualan";
$stmt=$con->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array(":id_pelanggan"=>$id_pelanggan));
$row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$id_penjualan=$row['id_penjualan'];
if($stmt->rowCount()>0)
{
$query2="SELECT SUM(subtotal) AS total, SUM(jumlah) as total_jml
     FROM tb_detail_penjualan
     WHERE id_penjualan=:id_penjualan";
$stmt2=$con->prepare($query2);
$stmt2->execute(array(":id_penjualan"=>$id_penjualan));
$stmt2->execute();
$row2=$stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$no=1;
while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{?>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><?php echo $no++;?></td>
    <td> <?php echo $row['id_penjualan'] ;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['nama_dpn'] ;?>&nbsp;<?php echo $row['nama_blk'] ;?> </td>
    <td><?php echo date('d F y', strtotime($row['tanggal_blj'])); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row2['total_jml']; ?></td>
    <td> <?php $harga = $row2['total'] ?> <?php echo "Rp. " .number_format($harga, 0, ',', '.');?></td>
    <td>Rp. </td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <?php   
}
} else { ?>
    <p>Order history empty</p>
<?php }?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: What are table names in enligsh? It is hard to understand what are you trying to do without knowing what data is in which table...

Comment: jumlah is quantity, I try use  foreach and work, but if I use prepare statement it doesn't work, ..
tb_penjualana:transaction.
tb_detail_penjualan:detail transaction.

Comment: `$stmt2` is executed only once and `$row2` contains the first row of it and you never fetch additional rows from it... So if you print `$row2['total_jml']` several times in that loop, it still has the same data... Inside your loop you're only fetching more rows from `$stmt` into `$row` (so the first mysql query)

Comment: thank you for the answer. finally, I use foreach.

Comment: I have posted it as an answer, so you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 queries in your code:

1. `$query` executed with `$stmt`
2. `$query2` executed with `$stmt2` and you fetch first row in `$row2`.

Then you have a loop, where you are fetching all rows from `$stmt` via variable `$row`. So `$row` contains each time values from next row of the first query.

But inside the loop you are also outputting information from `$row2`, which doesn't change (it is still the first row fetched before the loop), so each time it prints the same output.